# Are WCF callbacks only for short-lived connections?

Tags: wcf

I was told that WCF callbacks are not to be used in situations when the connection is kept for a long time (say, a week) even though the callback operations themselves are short (< 1s). Is this true? Where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I still got no reply, I'll add my own thoughts.

To answer the actual question, no, WCF connections can be used for long-term connections. Nothing in the design prevents that by itself, and it's not an anti-pattern.

However, since any kind of connection is unstable to a certain degree, it is required to handle (both intended and accidental) connection faults. Clients need to be able to reconnect, and servers should not choke on lost connections. In the specific case of WCF the server should also be able to persist and restore its data no matter when or how it is disposed.